# Which test to use to measure if target has been met?

Tags: spss, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, stata, sas

The photo below is an example of the result i would like to obtain using the test which i cannot find in the article itself, i was hoping maybe any of you would know. I have tried to carry out chi square test for goodness of fit but what i really want is to able to compare BP between two groups (men vs. women). Would anyone shine a light and tell me what the test name is called?

[image]

Comment: Unless I missed something there's no test at all. Possibly a trend test could be carried out since BP is treated as a categorical variable with ordered levels. What are the degrees of freedom for the test used in this article?

Comment: I went through the article and they did not mention degrees of freedom

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chi-square test to examine whether the number of patients in each blood pressure category is similar or different by sex.

You can easily perform a chi-square test in R:

```
# Make the table:
x <- matrix(c(98, 117, 94, 94, 155, 118), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE, dimnames=list(c("SBP and DBP <130/80", "SBP <130 or DBP <80", "SBP and DBP >= 130/80"), c("Males", "Females")))
# Check to see that it is correct:
print(x)

#                       Males Females
# SBP and DBP <130/80      98      94
# SBP <130 or DBP <80     117     155
# SBP and DBP >= 130/80    94     118

# Chi-square test:
chisq.test(x)

#     Pearson's Chi-squared test
#
# data:  x
# X-squared = 3.156, df = 2, p-value = 0.2064
```

The data here do not reject the null hypothesis. In other words, there is not evidence of a difference in BP group between males and females.

Comment: Your test--which the OP says she has already applied--lacks power because it does not account for the natural ordering of the categories (as intimated by a comment to the question posted by @chl). There seems to be some evidence of a shift of the males towards lower SBP and DBP relative to the females. Although I am not convinced that this would be significant (at a 5% level, say), it would be nice to conduct a more powerful and appropriate test before concluding there is no evidence of a difference.

Comment: OP "tried" to apply. You are correct that this test is limited. I didn't mean to conclude there isn't evidence, rather that I don't have sufficient evidence. Until someone conducts a more powerful test, etc. I don't have evidence. That being said, I'd be more worried about the data collection, etc. than the power of the test before actually making this type of conclusion.

Comment: That is good general advice (+1). I was moved to post the first comment because these data are getting near that gray area on the border between "significant" and not, which is where a little more effort to select a more powerful test can pay off. I also had in mind the idea that even if no appropriate test finds significant evidence, the next step might be to plan to collect additional data, in which case a more powerful test will reduce the subsequent data-collection budget.

Comment: Good points. A simple power analysis here would be good too.